# JavaScript- Click a certain button on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, automation

Here's a webpage : http://www.mirakee.com/milind_ek_kavi
Now this webpage contains around 1000's of post by this user, and I wish to like all of them at once. 
Each post contains a like button.
Now i want a script(bot type) that would click all the like buttons at once. and all of them get registered(accepted).
Please do tell me where and how to embed the script. 
Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE:** 
This is the HTML code for the like button:

```
<div>
                <span class="like_content post_zy2v7yjilw_like">
                    <a class="like-post" data-remote="true" data-method="post" rel="nofollow noopener" href="/posts/zy2v7yjilw/like">
                      <span class="heart"></span>
</a>
                  <a class="likes-count" rel="nofollow noopener" data-remote="true" href="/posts/zy2v7yjilw/likes">
                    46
</a>                </span>

                <span class="comment-icon"></span>
                <span class="comment-count">1</span>

                  <span class="reposts-icon"></span>
                  <a class="comment-count" rel="nofollow noopener" data-remote="true" href="/posts/zy2v7yjilw/reposts">
                    4
</a>              </div>
```

Comment: Rather than trying to programmatically click all the buttons - it would be better to find the function that the button click invokes (perhaps it gets the id from the button and updates a database - or something similar) and programmatically invoke that function for the id of the user involved. If a button click triggers the function "likePost(this.id)" then you can do that same thing without triggering the click.

Comment: @gavgrif where am I suppose to look for that function. Would inspect element work?

Comment: @gavgrif I've editted the question, please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

`$(".like-post").trigger("click");`

The main problem will be that it will trigger click only for elements which are actually available on page. I mean that the posts which are not loaded yet will have no effect of this code.

So, either you can first load all the posts by scrolling manually or you need to write script for that too.

Comment: I'll first load all the elements. 
where should I add this line?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: On chrome, right click --> inspect element. Click on "Console" tab. Paste that code and hit enter.

Comment: He would need to inject <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> has the page does not use jquery.

Comment: Oh! But I can see jQuery on that page. They have added in application JS file while assets creation.

Comment: @VikasTomar Well, then you can upvote and choose this as correct answer :)

Comment: @RohitVerma I injected button with alert(window.JQuery) and it returned undefined, so not sure what they are doing.

Comment: @RohitVerma Done.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `click()` function.

```
$(element).click();
```

But may be abusing a feature like that is illegal. I currently don't have access to your DOM on mobile, so you can add your own query instead of `element`